# How to align fieldLabel and textfield as single line in dialog in AEM 6.3

Tags: aem, aem-6

How to align fieldLabel and textfield as single line in dialog in AEM 6.3? But in AEM 6.2 it's showing Single line FieldLabel and Textfield.

Please find attachments         [AEM 6.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkJb7.png)
        [AEM 6.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bugfu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I was wondering about that. I have looked over every documentation from Adobe, found nothing that suggests that it's possible.

If you look at 6.1 dialog source, you'll see the form has `coral-Form--aligned` when in floating mode and `coral-Form--vertical` in fullscreen.

in 6.3 dialogs, it's always `coral-Form--vertical`
Also, if you look at the dialog JSP, in 6.3, at this path: `/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/dialog.jsp`  you'll see that they add `coral-Form--vertical` by default and there are no properties to change that behavior.

**So, it seems Adobe will keep the dialog style as vertical.**

> I don't recommend the following, but it is mentioned because it's possible:

If you really really want to force "aligned", you'll have to write a simple script to add `coral-Form--aligned` to the dialog form and remove `coral-Form--vertical`, I tried that, and it results in an unpleasant UI (see screenshot) that needs a few CSS fixes.

[image: UI screenshot after adding `coral-Form--vertical]